# If the dates in the sorted field are the same, how are they sorted?

Tags: soql, query

I am using "order by" clause for a date field but I couldn't understand the behavior when values are the same. I sense some inconsistencies in the query results but I haven't been able to identify them exactly.

Note: I couldn't find an answer to this in any documentation or Q&A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the documentation for [ORDER BY](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm)

> There’s no guarantee of the order of results unless you use an ORDER
> BY clause in a query.
>
> **And even if you use ORDER BY, the order of results can vary if there
> are duplicate values for the fields you’re using in the ORDER BY
> clause**. For example, if there a multiple Account records with the same
> Industry, the order of the results for this query can vary
> **To avoid this issue, add the Id (or any other field that is unique in the > results) to the ORDER BY clause**. For example:

If the date values are the same, there's no guarantee of consistency in the order. As noted in the documentation - you add the `Id` (or any other unique field) to the `ORDER BY` clause to get consistent results.

`SELECT Name FROM Account ORDER BY Date_Field__c, Id`